# Unhide until row + 1

Tags: excel, vba, offset

This is the current code I'm using to filter data and create multiple reports. It searches for text in column A (FS) and stops hiding rows until it reaches a blank cell then it hides everything again until it reaches the next text (LR).

I'm needing to keep that blank row, though, as it contains data I'm needing and then start the "hiding" process after this row. Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm a VBA novice.

```
Sub RunReport()

Set R = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
hiderow = False
For Each c In R.Cells
    If Left(c.Value, 2) = "FS" Then
        hiderow = False
    ElseIf Left(c.Value, 2) = "LR" Then
        hiderow = False
    ElseIf Left(c.Value, 2) = "SR" Then
        hiderow = False
    ElseIf Left(c.Value, 3) = "ROG" Then
        hiderow = False
    ElseIf Left(c.Value, 8) = "ST" Then
        hiderow = False
    ElseIf Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        hiderow = True
    End If
    If hiderow Then
        c.Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: put the `hiderow = False` as the first line inside the loop.

Comment: Well I'm trying to specifically filter based on these headers. The code you provided only filters out the blank cells and doesn't hide the appropriate data. I really just need it to be hiderow + 1, but can't figure out how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the only line needed in the loop is: `c.EntireRow.Hidden = Len(c.Value) = 0`

```
Sub RunReport()

Dim R as Range
Set R = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Dim c as Range
For Each c In R.Cells
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = Len(c.Value) = 0
Next c
End Sub
```